# What is the set of elements that HTML5 supports?

Tags: html

As I know, HTML5 brings in some new elements (like `<video>`), meanwhile, takes some elements (like `<plaintext>`) away.

After simple google searches, I didn't find an authoritative set of HTML5-supported elements. e.g. I thought `<math>` is supported by HTML5, but I couldn't find a HTML5 element list containing it.

I need an authoritative reference showing a concrete number (I thought this is deterministic, right?) of elements that HTML5 support.

By the way, I thought HTML5 support self-defined elements, e.g. `<myElement> something </myElement>`, right?

Comment: wat r u gonna do with the numbers ? go with its functionality

Comment: If only there was some sort of, you know... standard that defines all this, like a ["HTML5 standard"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), that would be amazing. `:P` ...or even better, a standard that actually lists all the types of HTML elements, some sort of [language reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, I totally agree with you. But I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why is this question down-voted? Is it unreasonable to want a single integrated list of HTML5 elements in the HTML, SVG and MathML namespaces, or that it is trivial to find one? Certainly, neither the HTML5 standard nor the language reference provides one.

Comment: @Alohci: I think the folks at [meta] will be interested in discussing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create any tag you like for your application!

but here is the most official list that I found [HTML5 New Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)

I hope it helps :)

UPDATE

Here is an interesting link you might find useful! [HTML5 Semantics](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html)

Comment: "Well you can create any tag you like for your application!" Except it won't validate.

Answer (score 0):

The list of all valid HTML5 elements (without [autonomous custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#autonomous-custom-element)) as listed in the [(non-normative) section on Elements of the HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-3) (wait for the page to load!) is:

> a abbr address area article aside audio b base bdi bdo blockquote body
>   br button canvas caption cite code col colgroup data datalist dd del
>   details dfn dialog div dl dt em embed fieldset figcaption figure
>   footer form h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 head header hgroup hr html i iframe img
>   input ins kbd label legend li link main map mark math menu meta meter
>   nav noscript object ol optgroup option output p param picture pre
>   progress q rp rt ruby s samp script section select slot small source
>   span strong style sub summary sup svg table tbody td template textarea
>   tfoot th thead time title tr track u ul var video wbr

I am counting 114 elements without elements from svg and mathml standards, except `<svg>` and `<math>` itself.